# Setting the IIS application pool that a LightSwitch application is deployed to

Tags: iis, msdeploy, visual-studio-lightswitch

How do you set the IIS application pool that a LightSwitch application is deployed to ?

For both IIS 6 and 7 ?

When using MsDeploy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use msdeploy.exe to deploy just the app pool to IIS 7, you can use the [appPoolConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569070%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider. (The provider is not supported on IIS 6.)

If you’re using msdeploy.exe and want to include the application pool as part of an application deployment, you can use the [-enableLink:AppPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569028%28WS.10%29.aspx)  or [-enableLink:AppPoolExtension switches](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569028%28WS.10%29.aspx) (they are equivalent).

Also, if you want to set the .NET Framework version of the application pool, you can use the [Web Deploy appPoolNetFx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418388%28WS.10%29.aspx)  provider.

Here are some references if you're going to use IIS Manager:

To set the application pool in IIS 7, go to the [Application Pools](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools)  reference page and follow the steps under *“How to configure the application pool for an existing site or application”*.

To set the application pool in IIS 6, see [Configuring Application Pools in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2a231dcb-d786-4b6d-b3ba-bda04061a5e7.mspx?mfr=true).